# Back in time on Elementary OS

Tags: software-installation, backup

I did my backups with back in time before I moved to Elementary.
Now I installed back in time and I do have to start the (root)-version - but it won´t start.
How do I get the thing running?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you get an error message when trying to start the application? What do you mean by "the root version"?
See also: https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/issues

Comment: This is a limitation in `pkexec` that is it refuses to run a process in the background. We should check if there is already a bug report pending…

Comment: (Answer based on http://askubuntu.com/questions/608419/trying-to-execute-a-process-with-pkexec-asynchronously-and-get-refusing-to-rend)

Comment: No, there is no error-message.
Yeah, there is a "normal" version installed, and a root-version - you have to take the root-version, so that you can find the mounted directories under mnt (if you mount it there)

Answer (score 2):

You can start it from a terminal with `pkexec backintime-qt4`.

Actually as a bugfix you can create a script `/usr/local/bin/backintime-pkexec`

```
#!/bin/sh
pkexec "/usr/bin/backintime-qt4" "$@"
```

1. Save these lines as `/usr/local/bin/backintime-pkexec`
2. Make it executable: `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/backintime-pkexec`
3. And finally replace in the file `/usr/share/applications/backintime-qt4-root.desktop` the line `Exec=pkexec backintime-qt4` to `Exec=/usr/local/bin/backintime-pkexec`

Comment: Works as expected. This answer should be accepted.